# How to render dynamic route when a new blog post is added in nextjs without running npm run build command

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have developed a blog app in nextjs, while adding new blog in the database, it does not render the page with new route, instead I have to manually do npm run build to pre-render new blog. Until then it keeps showing not found error.

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const posts = await service.getAllPosts();
  const paths = posts.map((post) => ({
    params: { slug: post.slug },
  }));
  return { paths, fallback: 'blocking' };
}

export async function getStaticProps({
  params,
}: GetStaticPropsContext<{ slug: string }>) {
  const slug = params?.slug as string;

  try {
    const { post } =
      await service.getPost(slug);
    return {
      props: { post },
      revalidate: 10,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    return { props: { post: {}, error: error.message} };
  }
}

const Blog = ({ post }: Props) => {

return <div>
<p>{post.title}
</div>
```

}

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

When I add a new blog post, I does not render on the client side when i visit: https://example.com/blog/new-slug

Comment: [`fallback: 'blocking'`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-paths#fallback-blocking) should allow for new paths to be generated when they are requested without having to fully re-build the app. Are you certain the slug you're accessing to is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you are using `getStaticProps`, which only gets called when the website is built. It is useful for pages that don't change very often.

If you want the website to update any time you post something, you should be using [getServerSideProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props) that gets called each time you are visiting the page.

Alternatively you could also do client side fetching, if you don't mind about the SEO.

Another way if you want to keep the performance of a static page, is to use the [revalidate](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-props#revalidate) option in the `getStaticProps`. It tells the page to rebuild after a time interval.

Comment: hey thanks :) SEO is primarily important since it is a blog. I think I should be doing getServerSideProps.

Comment: Nice! I added one last way that I overlooked and would allow you to keep your code as it is, if you don't mind about real time update.

Comment: Take a look at https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration#on-demand-revalidation-beta, the ISR might be a better approach.

Comment: _"you are using getStaticProps, which only gets called when the website is built"_ - this is not entirely accurate. When using `fallback: true`/`fallback: 'blocking'` or [Incremental Static Regeneration](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration) (which OP is using), `getStaticProps` will get called when _some_ requests come in.

Comment: @juliomalves Indeed, I edited my answer later to add ISR. Guess I could edit my first sentence to make it clearer